# Как получить параметры тега TinyXml на C++?

Tags: xml, xmlparser, c++

У меня есть код XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
    <testfield>test value</testfield>
    <servertime>2009-08-27 10:49:43</servertime>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
    <test_text>Слово</test_text>
</response>
```

Парсер TinyXml. Мне нужно получить значение **testfield**. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html

Comment: Блин нифига не понять ПЛС можешь объяснить! У меня DEV-C++.